# VBA and overdraft issues

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I've created a VBA program thats connects to Access and inputs and outputs correctly.
I'm having problems trying to get the available balance to show properly though.  Currently I have:

```
range("a6").select
set my recordset etc.
activecell = 0 - money out  ( this works If I'm within my overdraft. I changed it to)
If 0 - money out = 0 then
  activecell = money in + money out
  else
  activecell = 0-money out
End if
```

This still works the same as above if I'm within my overdraft but if I'm in a credit balance it keeps the cell blank.  The code runs perfectly so I'm confused..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `overdraft` and `credit balance` are sheets? is this what you look for `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("overdraft").Range("A6").Value2 = my_precompute_value` or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly you need to change this:

```
If 0 - money out = 0 then
```

to this:

```
If 0 - money out >= 0 then
```